# converting my console application to Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

ok so for a much more in detail(with code) question go to:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2142977

I just cannot type all that code again.

But for a description, I have a Qt form that what it does is translates a message so it has two options: translate a message from English to gibberish and from gibberish to English (radio buttons to select; engLang and fakeLang) I want my if statement(as shown in the linked webpage) to for the if condition to check if engLang is checked and then check if fakeLang is checked and then depending on which one is checked use the appropriate code to translate it.

Finally my last question would be how do I make it so when I press translate it runs those if statements and displays the new message in the second box (labeled secondMessage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember my first time I was trying to make a GUI from a console program.  The first time is hard.  Be sure to read through the examples that Qt has.  Here is a starting point for a way to accomplish what you want to do.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-widgets.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/all-examples.html

You can also find examples and tutorials built into the Qt Creator Welcome screen.

Good luck.

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QComboBox>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();
public slots:
    void translate();
private:
    QTextEdit * lhs;
    QTextEdit * rhs;
    QComboBox * mode_comboBox;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout * vlayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QHBoxLayout * hlayout = new QHBoxLayout;

    mode_comboBox = new QComboBox;
    mode_comboBox->addItems(QStringList() << "Encrypt" << "Decrypt");
    vlayout->addWidget(mode_comboBox);

    lhs = new QTextEdit;
    lhs->setText("Enter Text Here.");
    rhs = new QTextEdit;
    rhs->setText("See the output here.");
    rhs->setReadOnly(true);

    QObject::connect(lhs, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(translate()));
    QObject::connect(mode_comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(translate()));
    hlayout->addWidget(lhs);
    hlayout->addWidget(rhs);

    vlayout->addLayout(hlayout);
    this->setLayout(vlayout);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

void Widget::translate()
{
    if(mode_comboBox->currentText() == "Encrypt")
    {
        QString str = lhs->toPlainText();
        rhs->setText(str.toUpper());
    }
    else
    {
        QString str = lhs->toPlainText();
        rhs->setText(str.toLower());
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "widget.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: In your code, where it says Widget I replace that with my class name right? even where it says QWidget?

Comment: QWidget is different.  It is the base class, or what your class derives from.

Comment: Here are some links for an introduction on what classes are.  They are very useful for GUI's and for complex programs.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/ http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2/

Comment: in widget.h why do you have two
QTextEdit * lhs/rhs? (I believe they are called pointers) wouldn't they both be pointing to the same thing.
Also what is the combo box

Comment: And finally why does it not need specific names of the features in the form. Text boxes for example. If it does where would I replace

Comment: Have you compiled and ran it yet?

Comment: At the top of your .h you should have `#include <QComboBox>`.  Is it there?

Comment: yes I copied and pasted exactly what you put obviously trading widget for translationForm
These are all the errors:

Comment: nevermind not enough rep. can you email me. zachbresser@yahoo.com

Comment: Ok so I got your code to work but where do I enter my encryption code. Because right now it just changes Hello to HELLO if i select encrypt. or Hello to hello if I select decrypt. I see where it says the function to change it to upper or lower. But what do I change on that.

Comment: Using `QString str`, go and change it to what you want, or save an modified version of it into another QString variable, and when you are done, set the text for the rhs, or the "Right hand side" text edit box.

Comment: thank you. You are a god. If I could vote up I would for you.

Comment: Don't forget to browse through the examples Qt has to get feel for how to do more with Qt, signals and slots, objects, classes, etc.

Comment: where can I find examples about signals and slots I am so confused by this.

Comment: After you know what a class/object is in the context of OOP (object oriented programming), the idea of connecting one object to another is a logical step necessary for GUI's and other types of interaction.  Here is the official documentation on it http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html .

Comment: Almost all of Qt's examples show ways that signals and slots are used.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you're asking; I acknowledge you tried to split it into context and questions, but the text could use some proof-reading. Also, the code could and should be copied here (you don't have to type it again, that's what Ctrl+C is for) because without indentation nor colors it's really difficult to follow even a simple code.

As for what I've understood of your questions, since this is more about Qt and not about the processing, you should post your Qt code. In the meantime, I would advise you to look at the documentation and [examples](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_Use_QPushButton) of the class QRadioButton, especially isChecked(). If you want to run the processing after pushing a button, you just have to connect() the event pressed() to a slot of a custom class which will do the processing.

Comment: and could you give me some documentation on how to do that connecting?

Comment: connect() is the spine of Qt, you'll find it in any tutorial. But I would recommend the official Qt [developer's guide](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/gettingstartedqt.html) on their website. There is a link to signals and slots. I've seen above that you're not entirely sure what a pointer is, so I should remind you that Qt is using a lot of subtle C++ characteristics. You should do things step by step by learning C++ first (pointers go all the way back from C in fact) in order to be ready for what's to come.

Comment: Also if you can speak French the tutorials on C, C++ and Qt on the [siteduzero](http://www.siteduzero.com/informatique/tutoriels/programmez-avec-le-langage-c/introduction-a-qt) are very famous.
Finally, as a quick reminder, useful answers should be marked as such by clicking the up arrow next to the post (especially when the author is helping you a lot in the comments like phyatt did). The tick is made to indicate the topic is solved (obviously it isn't), which will attract less helpers on your topic... But it still is necessary to tick an answer when it's solved the topic, indeed.

Comment: no it is solved. He just did it different than I asked and that is perfectly fine cuz his way is better.